# living bytes increase without leak

Tags: iphone, memory, instruments, memory-leaks

I'm making iPhone development and having (like lot of peoples) problems with memory management.

I'm often using "Instruments" in order to fix memory I have forgot to dealloc.
**So I don't have memory leak anymore !**
BUT... When I'm using the app the "Live Bytes" in Instruments is always increasing.

At the launch my App is using 4MB and going back and forward few times in my UINavigationView 10MB (still "without" memory leak).

[image: Live Bytes always increasing]

Martin Magakian

Comment: maybe you have some variables that you're using and keep on growing in memory (e.g: you have an array to which you add more and more objects). The 'Analyze' option from Xcode 4 might also help you in detecting some possible leaks/issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be bloat, not a true leak.

What you want to do is use that Mark Heap button a time or two, then look at the heap shots.

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ has lots more.